# GRUB config file booting issue

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader, grub

I have installed Linux and Windows on same system, Linux is loaded by default on system startup and from Linux I restart the OS. What I want to do is on next restart I want to automatically load Windows OS, i.e. user don't need to select the OS. and when Windows is restarted the System should load Linux again. Mean I need to load Windows only one time after restart of linux. Can I do it with GRUB? as in GRUB if i put the index number of OS in `default` directive of boot loader it will become permanant, but I need one time change only.

edit: I have come across a command which is `grub-reboot` which do the above task according to its manual... but its not working for me on debian.., yet not sure why... any luck with any one?

edit: This command works on ubuntu and I have to transfer my code to UBuntu text only version. and problem resolved.

Comment: Are you using the legacy GRUB or GRUB2?

Comment: Legacy GRUB on Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `grub-reboot` command is solution for this problem, don't work on `debian` same case here with me, it worked on `Ubuntu` and `Redhat`

Comment: This is what I have told already in my question.. however thanks for reply..

Answer (score 1):

To change the default OS to boot, you will need to change the value in:

```
/boot/grub/menu.lst
```

I cannot see any way that you would be able to do *exactly* what you want. If you want to play around a bit, what you could do is the following:

Have 2 versions of your `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file, one for booting Linux as default, and one for booting Windows as default. Secondly, you will need to install (on Windows) a driver so that you can access your Linux partitions (easy enough if using EXT2/EXT3, not so much when using EXT4) Have a look [here](http://www.soluvas.com/read-browse-explore-open-ext2-ext3-ext4-partition-filesystem-from-windows-7/) or if you have EXT2/3 use [this](http://www.fs-driver.org/).

Now, what you will need to do is create a script that runs at startup (of both OSes seperately) to swop **AND RENAME** the two `menu.lst` files that you have.

Sorry that I cannot think of a more eloquent way of doing it. If anyone else has a suggestion, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. it may be considered as work arround.. first I am investigation for a direct way.

Comment: Is it possible with GRUB 2?

Comment: @Ummar - Not too sure. GRUB2 does not use the `menu.lst` file.